# Storing an array of searchable values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I need to store the role ID and role name in each document in my `Users` collection. I need to be able to say "Get Users that have xyz role" or "Get users that have a role who's name contains 'XYZ'", stuff like that.

Is that even possible in Mongo?

Right now, I'm storing data like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$id": "4fe30e3db92f5d2a5c000000"
    },
    "alias": "rogue_coder",
    "display_name": "Rogue Coder",
    "email": "rogue@example.com",
    "roles": {
        "4fe30e5fb92f5d6f53000000": "Super Administrator"
    }
}
```

With that, I can see if a user has a given role, but I can't get all users who have a role that contains the word "Super" for example. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what your attempting to do, you may have to store role_id & role_name in separate arrays, like such:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$id": "4fe30e3db92f5d2a5c000000"
    },
    "alias": "rogue_coder",
    "display_name": "Rogue Coder",
    "email": "rogue@example.com",
    "role_names": [
        "Super Administrator"
    ],
    "role_ids" : [
        "4fe30e5fb92f5d6f53000000"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB has support for the regular expression for matching key's values.

Take look at this [MongoDB Regular Expression](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but you may try a bit like this

```
db.collection.find( { roles: { /super.*/i } );
```